# Updating RecyclerView with adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, countdowntimer, android-recyclerview

I've implemented a RecyclerView which has a user interface of a timer counting down.  I created a BroadcastService class which creates a CountDownTimer and broadcasts the timer's contents in the onTick() method to my MainActivity, where I use a BroadCast receiever to update the UI.

My BroadcastReceiver is only receiving the initial value from the BroadcastService. I figured that's because I hadn't notified the recycler view's adapter that the data had changed. However, because of variable scope, I'm unable to access my adapter from my broadcast receiver.

Perhaps I have a fundamental lack of understanding of variable scope, but how can I access the adapter from

```
            adapter = new DataAdapter(getApplicationContext(), data);
```

in my broadcast receiver class? Because right now it's not being recognized.

This is my class definition + onCreate()

```
public class Profile_Page extends  ActionBarActivity implements DataAdapter.ClickListener {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    public DataAdapter adapter;
    private Context context;
    String currentUser;
    Data current = new Data();

    final List<Data> data = new ArrayList<>();
    public static String BROADCAST_ACTION =
            "packagename.countdown_br";

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(BROADCAST_ACTION);
        filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        registerReceiver(br, filter);

        startService(new Intent(this, Broadcast_Service.class));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile__page);

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("ParseClass");
        query.whereEqualTo("author", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView); 
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override

            public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) { 
                if (e == null) {
                    for (ParseObject getData : list)
                    {
                        current.1= getData.getString("1");
                        current.2= getData.getString("2");
                        current.3= getData.getString("3");
                        current.4= getData.getString("4");
                        current.5= getData.getString("5");


                        data.add(current);

                    }
                }
                else {

                     }


                adapter = new DataAdapter(getApplicationContext(), data);

                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter); //set recyclerView to this adapter


            }



        });


    }
```

And here's my Broadcast Receiver code [which is also in MainActivity.java]

```
public BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            updateGUI(intent);
            //HOW TO NOTIFY DATA SET CHANGE

        }
    };

public void updateGUI(Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
            long millisUntilFinished = intent.getLongExtra("countdown", 0);
            current.goalTimer = String.valueOf(intent.getExtras().getLong("countdown") / 1000);

        }


    }
```

And, if it is of any use, here's my Broadcast Service class:

```
public class Broadcast_Service extends Service {
    private final static String TAG = "BroadcastService";
    LocalBroadcastManager broadcastManager;
    public static final String COUNTDOWN_BR = "packagename.countdown_br";
    Intent bi = new Intent(COUNTDOWN_BR);

    CountDownTimer cdt = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i(TAG, "Starting timer...");

        cdt = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                bi.putExtra("countdown", millisUntilFinished);
                sendBroadcast(bi);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Log.i(TAG, "Timer finished");
            }
        };

        cdt.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        cdt.cancel();
        Log.i(TAG, "Timer cancelled");
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, extend the BroadcastReciever class as follows:

```
public class MyReciever extends BroadcastReciever{
    private Profile_Page activity;

    public MyReciever(Profile_Page activity){
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        activity.updateGUI(intent);
    }
}
```

Create a static instance of your activity and pass it to your receiver.

```
public class Profile_Page extends  ActionBarActivity implements DataAdapter.ClickListener {
    private static Profile_Page instance;
    private MyReciever myReceiver;
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        instance = this;
        myReceiver = new MyReciever(instance);
        ...
    }

    public void updateGUI(Intent intent) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now you can access your adapter quite easily. Hope this helps.

Comment: Don't keep a strong reference to activity in any of the subclasses. It will not be garbage collected most of the cases. Use WeakReference instead.

Comment: @Anoop From my understanding, the instance of the receiver is created within the activity and will be destroyed once the finish() method is called. Can you refer me to any documentation relating to garbage collection in this particular scenario?